# Contex menu with pure JS

Tags: javascript, css

I am begginer at programming.
My goal is to write contex menu on pure JavaScript.
Ideally it has to be like that : https://jqueryui.com/menu/
I have already HTML unordered list from JSON.
How do I customise it? Do I have adding styles while HTML is building or there are another ways to solve problem. I can use only pure JS, no frameworks.
My code is below.

```
function buildList(data, isSub){
    var html = (isSub)?'<div>':''; // Wrap with div if true
    html += '<ul>';
    for(item in data){
        html += '<li>';
        if(typeof(data[item].sub) === 'object'){ // An array will return 'object'
            if(isSub){
                html += '<a href="' + data[item].link + '">' + data[item].name + '</a>';
            } else {
                html += data[item].id; // Submenu found, but top level list item.
            }
            html += buildList(data[item].sub, true); // Submenu found. Calling recursively same method (and wrapping it in a div)
        } else {
            html += data[item].id // No submenu
        }
        html += '</li>';
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    html += (isSub)?'</div>':'';
    console.log(html);
    return html;
}
var hide =  document.getElementsByClassName('seeMenu')[0];
hide.addEventListener('click',function () {
    var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0];
    var hide =  document.getElementsByClassName('seeMenu')[0];
    menu.style.display = "inline-block";
    hide.style.display = "none";
});
(function(){
    // Json config for menu
    var JSON = {
    menu: [
        {id: 'First',sub: [
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-0',link: '0-0', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-1',link: '0-1', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-2',link: '0-2', sub: null}
            ]
        },
        {id: 'Second',sub: null},
        {id: 'Third',sub: [
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-0',link: '2-0', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-1',link: '2-1', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2',link: '2-2', sub: [
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-0',link: '2-2-0', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-1',link: '2-2-1', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-2',link: '2-2-2', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-3',link: '2-2-3', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-4',link: '2-2-4', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-5',link: '2-2-5', sub: null},
                {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-2-6',link: '2-2-6', sub: null}
            ]},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-3',link: '2-3', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-4',link: '2-4', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 2-5',link: '2-5', sub: null}
            ]
        },
        {id: 'Fourth',sub: null},
         {id: 'Five',sub: [
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-5',link: '0-5', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-6',link: '0-6', sub: null},
            {name: 'lorem ipsum 0-7',link: '0-7', sub: null}
            ]
        }
    ]
}    
    document.write(buildList(JSON.menu,false));
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sound like you're looking for a complete **custom** solution. I won't give you that, but here's a couple of suggestions:

1. Solution #1 would be to not do this in 3 steps (hard-code JSON, then generate HTML off of it, then attach jquery-ui menu behavior). Instead, hard-code complete HTML, just like jquery-ui-menu expects. On the webpage that you pointed to (jquery-ui menu docs), there is "view source" link, which will give you a sample HTML snippet of exactly that. Then, if you need to not show this menu after the user clicks on something, then maybe use [jQuery `toggle` function](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) to show/hide that menu.
2. Solution #2: keep your approach (the 3-step process) and use debugging methods (e.g. `window.console.log`) to monitor your **customization** progress (which you haven't specified at all: customize what? how?).

---

Ah, screw it, here's the solution:

replace either this line:
`var html = (isSub)?'<div>':'';`
with
`var html = (isSub)?'<div class="menu">':'';`

**or** replace this line
`html += '<ul>';`
with 
`html += '<ul class="class">';`

See what works better. It appears that your seeMenu-click code is looking for element with class "menu", while your `buildList` isn't "prepping" for that. Note that I have not checked whether `buildList` actually produces valid HTML (see solution #1 above).

Comment: What I have meant about customization.. How I can access to recently created DOM elements. How to hide nested list items?Is there way to realise behavior of  CSS "hover" pseudoclass in JS?

Comment: It's easier with jQuery. Accessing elements: https://goo.gl/c70fbt (e.g. `$("div.class-name")` or `$("div#di-id")`. Maybe you can use this or similar to hide sublist: `$(".menu ul li ul").hide()` (also jQuery). jQuery function for "hover" is also called `hover`: https://goo.gl/n7rtZ8

Comment: Can't do that because I can use only pure JS.

Comment: Ok, then. It's very easy to write maching native JS for that.